# Missing Spring Initializr for stream

Tags: java, spring-cloud-dataflow

Using [this web site](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/), I'm not able anymore to consume the link in the picture. The link always return:

> 404 Not Found: Requested route ('start-scs.cfapps.io') does not exist.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the URL was pointing to but the spring initializer is at https://start.spring.io.

From there you can search for the dependency and download the boot app with it pre-packed in the maven or gradle file.

[image]

Comment: For spring cloud data flow the spring initializer  was different.

Comment: You could run your own version of the initializer, but yeah I Wouldn't know what version you'd need. Sorry.
https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/

Answer (score 0):

Finally the web site for Spring cloud data flow stream app is back online https://start-scs.cfapps.io/